# Printing Parse Class into UILabel (SWIFT)

Tags: ios, iphone, parse-platform, uilabel

I have an app, in which I want to print different Parse objects into different UILabels.

Is it possible to print Parse object into a UILabel in SWIFT 2.0+?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Let's say your Parse object has a value for key `objectDescription` which is a string.
You would call a `objectForKey` method on this object to get the value and show it in a label.

```
yourLabel.text = yourParseObject.objectForKey("objectDescription") as? String
```

Comment: Yes, but only if Places is an instance of an object which should be a variable with a name that does not start with a capital letter. What you wrote looks more like a class method.

Comment: Places is a class in my Parse database, here I have stored multiple places. - I have a bunch of cells, and therefor looking for a general way to do this. So that when a user taps on a cell - He is shown a UILabel with the place name.

Comment: You have to load objects you wanna show from the database. Then `inCellForRowAtIndexPath` extract the data you need from the object and set it as a label's text.

Comment: I have already used that method, I am in a new viewcontroller. - Here I want to make a sort of a review controller - Where I need to print the Place name into a UILabel - I have a problem doing that - I can't see how your method works in my instance.

Comment: It is impossible to help without looking into the code. Post the code your are having problems with